# Button hide on click is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

Can anyone help me out?? I added a JS code to make my button invisible on click and the text below visible.. It works on js fiddle but when I upload it online it doesn't work... 
https://jsfiddle.net/kraftpanda/wdc7c2ue/

```
<button id="theButton" class="btn">Click to View Phone Number</button>
<div id="theDiv" style="display:none;"><p><h3>Call Us: + 91 96000 72298 / 044-65652298</p></div>

$("#theButton").click(function(){
    $("#theButton").hide();
    $("#theDiv").show();
})

    .btn {
  background: #d93470;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d93470, #b82b53);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d93470, #b82b53);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d93470, #b82b53);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d93470, #b82b53);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d93470, #b82b53);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Sorry for not providing more details... http://exitoautomation.com is the website.. I added the css to css file, HTML to index page and script to a button.js file and linked the home page to it using

Comment: As you said, there's clearly nothing wrong with the code. Are you missing a reference to jQuery, or are you not deploying all of the necessary files? If you open your browser's developer tools, are there any errors, 404 or otherwise?

Comment: Is this how you have your code arranged in your document? Because javascript should go in between `<script> ... </script>` tags and CSS should be inside `<style> ... </style>` tags. jsFiddle just does it for you, that's why your code works there.

Comment: Sorry for not providing more details... http://exitoautomation.com is the website.. I added the css to css file, HTML to index page and script to a button.js file and linked the home page to it using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your Javascript code into `<script>` tags and your css into `<style>` tags, like this:

```
<button id="theButton" class="btn">Click to View Phone Number</button>
<div id="theDiv" style="display:none;"><p><h3>Call Us: + 91 96000 72298 / 044-65652298</p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#theButton").click(function(){
    $("#theButton").hide();
    $("#theDiv").show();
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .btn {
  background: #d93470;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d93470, #b82b53);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d93470, #b82b53);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d93470, #b82b53);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d93470, #b82b53);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d93470, #b82b53);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

Also, make sure that you have `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags as well, or, in short, that your html is valid. I would watch a tutorial about html on youtube if I were you. In a few minutes you will get a lot of help. If it will still not work after you deploy, then clear the browser cache and look for errors in your console and network tabs of the browser console.

EDIT: The problem is that your code executes before the button is created and when you add the handler to the button, it does not exist. Later the button is created without the handler. So you can change your JS this way:

```
$(function() {
    $("#theButton").click(function(){
        $("#theButton").hide();
        $("#theDiv").show();
    });
});
```

Notice that you wrap your functionality into a loaded handler.

Comment: Sorry for not providing more details... http://exitoautomation.com is the website.. I added the css to css file, HTML to index page and script to a button.js file and linked the home page to it using <script type="text/javascript" src="js/button.js"></script>

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and it still doesn't work. If I add the code directly to individual pages then it works but if I call then it doesn't

Comment: By "if I call" what do you mean? Are you using script tags with outer source? If so, are you sure your path is correct and the file can also be accessed?

Comment: If we are talking about <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script> then you might want to have an extra slash in the path, like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>

Comment: when I copy the JS code directly to the botton of index page instead of calling it using <script type="text/javascript" src="js/button.js"></script> then it works.. I used the extra slash like you mentioned.. still can't call it externally

Comment: You did not explain what did you try and how did it fail. What do you mean by calling it externally?

Comment: Thanks a ton.. You were really helpful.. I fixed it .. I somehow messed up adding the code in jquery.min file.. when I fixed it the code works.. Thank you so much

Comment: @Vijayaraj, I am glad to help. If the answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it.